# How to modify IIS permissions to run batch scripts in PHP?

Tags: php, iis

I am trying to have a PHP file call a Windows batch script using

`exec("runPy.bat");`

I have also tried

`exec("cmd /c \\server\somePath\runPy.bat");`

It doesn't matter what I try, the batch script doesn't work. And I don't get any errors. After much research I found a post saying that the problem may be due to privaleges: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11613662

Can anyone show me safe/proper way to set up permissions so that I can call batch scripts in IIS? Or is it unsafe in general to do that? Using IIS8 if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

To run batch, you need to use `cmd`, which you can call via:

```
system("cmd /c C:[path to file]");
```

Comment: that does the same thing as exec for me. The script isn't run but I don't get any errors.

Comment: Try grabbing the entire output with `exec("cmd /c C:[path to file]", $output)` by passing the second argument and see what the entire thing is giving you. If you're getting literally nothing back, it's probably a path or permission issue. Be sure PHP has the ability to run the script, as it's probably only accessible by your user, and PHP isn't running as your user.